# How do I fix a segmentation fault - SEGV_MAPERR - in a C program that reads a file?

Tags: file, unix, memory, segmentation-fault

**How do I fix a segmentation fault (SEGV_MAPERR - Address not mapped to object) in a C program that uses functions to read a text file?** FILE pointers are used to open, read, and close the file. The program is run using SuperPutty and UNIX.

The segmentation fault occurs at "while (fgets(buff, 100, fptr))" in the read() function.

**Error in UNIX:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault
si_code: 1 - SEGV_MAPERR - Address not mapped to object.**

CODE:

```
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h> 


int openFile(FILE *fptr, char filePath[100]);
void read (FILE *fptr);
int closeFile(FILE *fptr);

//MAIN function
int main (){

    FILE *fptr = NULL;
    char fileLocation[100] = "/export/home/czubgd/develop/dsal/src/example2File";

    openFile(fptr,fileLocation);
    read(fptr);
    closeFile(fptr);

    return 0;
}


//FUNCTION #1: Opens the file.
int openFile (FILE *fptr, char filePath[100])
{
    if ((fptr = fopen(filePath,"r")) == NULL)
    {   
        // Program exits if the file pointer returns NULL.
        printf("Error while opening file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //Program returns 0 when successful
        printf("File opened successfully. Path: %s",filePath);
        return 0;
    }
}


//FUNCTION #2: Closes the file.
int closeFile (FILE *fptr)
{
    fclose(fptr);
    if(fclose(fptr) != 0)
    {
        //Program prints error message and returns 1 when error occurs.
        fprintf(stderr, "Error closing file: %s\n\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //Program prints message for successfully closing the file.
        printf("File closed successfully.");
        return 0;
    }
}


//FUNCTION #3: Reads first and third column in each line of the file.
void read (FILE *fptr)
{
    char buff[100];
    const char s[2] = ",";
    char *token;
    int count =1;
        
    //loop through each line of file    
    while (fgets(buff, 100, fptr))//**Segmentation fault**SEGV_MAPERR - Address not mapped to object
    {
        // get the first token 
        token = strtok(buff, s);
   
        // walk through other tokens 
        while( token != NULL ) 
        {
            //print only if 1st or 3rd token
            if (count == 1 || count == 3)
            {
                printf( " %s", token );                                 
            }
            count++;
            if (count == 2)
            {
                printf(" --");                              
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, s);
        }
        
        //reset counter for outer while loop
        count = 1;
        printf("\n");           
    }
}
```

Comment: openFile seems to be intended to give fptr back. Then it needs to have a `FILE **fp` as argument. In `openFile` you would write `if ((*fptr = fopen...` (note the additional `*`).

Comment: The rest can stay as it is with one exception. In `closeFile` you are closing twice. Remove the first occurrence of `fclose(fptr);`

Comment: @StephanSchlecht - You were right. My colleague pointed that out to me. He said to use GLOBAL variables or double pointers. Thanks.